# General solution for non linear ODE systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I need help to determine the general solution (or the flow) of a 2x2 nonlinear system for a particular case and in general how the general solution in nonlinear systems can be understood

We considerer the next non linear system:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^{\prime}(t)=y \\
y^{\prime}(t)=-x+\left(1-x^{2}\right) y
\end{array}\right.$$

and i want to find general solution. For my aproach i understand that you have to considerer the linearization of the system in the equilibrium point, i.e,

$$J(0,0)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$

and therefore the linear system is

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^{\prime}(t)=y, \\
y^{\prime}(t)=-x+y .
\end{array} \quad \text { Or } \quad\left(\begin{array}{l}
x \\
y
\end{array}\right)^{\prime}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array}\right]\left(\begin{array}{l}
x \\
y
\end{array}\right) .\right.$$

with $\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}$ eigenvalues and $v_1,v_2$ (determinated) eigenvectors. Then solution for the linear system is

$$(x(t),y(t)) = (C_1e^{\lambda_1t}v_1, C_2e^{\lambda_2t}v_2)$$

without going to the transformation in sin() or cos(). But my question is **What about the nonlinear part of the original system? How does it influence the linear solution?**

Comment: This is the equation of the Van der Pol oscillator. There is no analytic solution for this dynamical system; see e.g. https://doi.org/10.1002/zamm.200310040. In fact, most nonlinear dynamical systems do not have analytic solutions in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: ok I understand; then in that case finding an analytic expression for a nonlinear system would be a very particular case?

Comment: I ask because I need to create an example in which I can determine the explicit solution for nonlinear systems.

Comment: Take a simpler one such as the logistic equation.

Comment: Thank you so much! :D